# ASP Net Core Filepond load file from server

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1, filepond

I have a project where it uses Filepond to upload files and I need it to load file from server.

I already follow the [docs](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/filepond-object/#setting-initial-files)  but It doesn't work. The Filepond gives error `Error during load 400` and it even doesn't send the request to load the file from server

This is my javascript

```
let pond = FilePond.create(value, {
            files: [
                {
                    // the server file reference
                    source: 'e958818e-92de-4953-960a-d8157467b766',

                    // set type to local to indicate an already uploaded file
                    options: {
                        type: 'local'
                    }
                }
            ]
        });

FilePond.setOptions({
    labelFileProcessingError: (error) => {
        return error.body;
    },
    server: {
        headers: {
            '@tokenSet.HeaderName' : '@tokenSet.RequestToken'
        },
        url: window.location.origin,
        process: (fieldName, file, metadata, load, error, progress, abort) => {
            // We ignore the metadata property and only send the file

            fieldName = "File";

            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append(fieldName, file, file.name);

            const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open('POST', '/UploadFileTemp/Process');
            request.setRequestHeader('@tokenSet.HeaderName', '@tokenSet.RequestToken');

            request.upload.onprogress = (e) => {
                progress(e.lengthComputable, e.loaded, e.total);
            };

            request.onload = function () {
                if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300) {
                    load(request.responseText);
                }
                else {
                    let errorMessageFromServer = request.responseText;
                    error('oh no');
                }
            };

            request.send(formData);

        },
        revert: "/UploadFileTemp/revert/",
        load: "/UploadFileTemp/load"


    }
})
```

This is my controller

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Load(string p_fileId)
        {
            //Code to get the files

            //Return the file 
            Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
            Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
            return PhysicalFile(filePath, "text/plain");
        }
```

**NB**

I already test my controller via postman and it works. I also check the `content-disposition` header

Comment: 400 error always caused by malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing.Use F12 to set break point to your javascript to check where the error happened.

Comment: I already use chrome developer tools but didn't know what to do since it returns no error in console, also in developer tools network tab it didn't send any XHR request to the server at all. I also don't know what line of code should I debug in my JS

Comment: it should fire a request to "/UploadFileTemp/load" if it reports a 400 error that means the request was attempted and is in the networ tab

Comment: @Rik I already double-check it, there's nothing on the network tab that is related to `load ` request.  By the way, I set the file for initial value for Filepond control, so I set the `files` property on document load method, is it wrong ?

Comment: @WibisonoIndrawan I'd advise to first set all the options and then set the files property. You're setting the files, and then you're telling FilePond where to find them, but it's probably already trying to load them but doesn't have an endpoint (yet).

Comment: @Rik wow you were right, thanks. Do you mind to post your comment as answer? so I can upvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd advise to first set all the options and then set the files property.

You're setting the `files`, and then you're telling FilePond where to find them, it's probably already trying to load them but doesn't have an endpoint (yet).

Restructuring the code to look like this should do the trick.

```js
let pond = FilePond.create(value, {
    server: {
        headers: {
            '@tokenSet.HeaderName': '@tokenSet.RequestToken',
        },
        url: window.location.origin,
        process: (fieldName, file, metadata, load, error, progress, abort) => {
            // your processing method
        },
        revert: '/UploadFileTemp/revert',
        load: '/UploadFileTemp/load',
    },
    files: [
        {
            // the server file reference
            source: 'e958818e-92de-4953-960a-d8157467b766',

            // set type to local to indicate an already uploaded file
            options: {
                type: 'local',
            },
        },
    ],
});
```